# Algebra - How do I setup such story problems using algebraic equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

On rainy mornings, John drinks exactly N cups of hot chocolate (assume that N is an integer). On mornings that are not rainy, John drinks exactly five cups of tea. Last week, John drank a total of 26 cups of tea and hot chocolate together. If during that week John drank 14 more cups of tea than hot chocolate, then how many rainy days were there last week?

*Assume 1 week is 7 days.

I can only derive the following equation from the problem above. How do I form more "equations" to help me solve the problem?

Can anyone guide me through to solve this problem?

1. John drank a total of 26 cups of tea and hot chocolate together: $N + (N+14) = 26$

Comment: That equation is not correct.  $N$ is the cups of chocolate John drinks $\textit {on a rainy day}$ not the total number of cups of chocolate John drinks.

Comment: @lulu can you show the steps to resolve such problem?

Comment: The posted solution of @Hume2 contains the correct equations.  To solve the system, rely on the fact that $A,B,N$ are non-negative integers.  Indeed, we must have $A\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.  If all else fails, you can just try those $8$ cases out one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the number of rainy days in the week and $B$ the non-rainy days in the week. Therefore:

1. John drank 26 cups of tea and chocolate together: $NA+5B=26$
2. John drank 14 more cups of tea than chocolate: $5B=14+AN$
3. There are 7 days in a week: $A+B=7$

Answer (score 1):

If he drank $26$ cups altogether and there were $14$ cups of tea more that chocolate, quick observation shows that he must have drunk 20 cups of tea and 6 cups of chocolate.

(Reminds me on the standard question: A bottle with a corc costs 11 cents where the bottle costs 10 cents more as the corc -- the answer is *not* $10+1$.)

Comment: how do I use algebraic equations to solve this problem

Comment: Not at all.  Why use Algebra for that task?

Comment: I wanted to find out different ways to solve the problem. Your solution is one interesting way to look at, I read about the baseball bat and ball problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Equations are as follows:

1. John drank a total of 26 cups of tea and hot chocolate together:  **N+(N+14)=26**
2. Number of Non-rainy days:  **N+14/5**
3. Number of rainy days:  **7-( N+14/5)**
4. N (cups of hot chocolates consumed per day) =   **N / [7-( N+14/5)]**

Comment: Note that $N$ is the number of cups of hot chocolate John drinks on *a rainy day*, not the number he drinks in a week.